# Dotnet 7 Swagger Client Code Generator with multiple route Route

Tags: visual-studio-2022, swagger-codegen

Using Minimal API

```
[Route("Auth")]
public class AuthAPI
{
    [HttpGet("Version")]
    public int Version()
    {
        return 1000;
    }
}

[Route("Common")]
public class CommonAPI
{
    [HttpGet("Version")]
    public int Version()
    {
        return 1000;
    }
}
```

The two different APIs are located within one endpoint. The snippet of the generated *swagger.json* are as below.

```
"/Auth/Version": {
    "get": {
        "tags": [
            "AuthAPI"
        ],
        "responses": {
            "200": {
                "description": "Success",
                "content": {
                    "text/plain": {
                        "schema": {
                            "type": "integer",
                            "format": "int32"
                        }
                    },
                    "application/json": {
                        "schema": {
                            "type": "integer",
                            "format": "int32"
                        }
                    },
                    "text/json": {
                        "schema": {
                            "type": "integer",
                            "format": "int32"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, "/Common/Version": {
    "get": {
        "tags": [
            "CommonAPI"
        ],
        "responses": {
            "200": {
                "description": "Success",
                "content": {
                    "text/plain": {
                        "schema": {
                            "type": "integer",
                            "format": "int32"
                        }
                    },
                    "application/json": {
                        "schema": {
                            "type": "integer",
                            "format": "int32"
                        }
                    },
                    "text/json": {
                        "schema": {
                            "type": "integer",
                            "format": "int32"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
```

However when I try to generate the client using VS2022 -> Right Click Solution -> Add -> Service Reference -> OpenAPI.

The C# code generated mixed different routes (classes) into one. With the similar function name `Version` renamed to `Version1` and `Version2` which is meaningless to my user.